# List of Ubuntu 18.04 Multimedia System Libraries

Tags: alsa, system, dynamic-linking

I'm compiling SDL2 into a static library. I wish to dynamically link to system libraries that are present on Ubuntu 18.04.
As I understand it, the following libraries are system libraries, i.e. they are present on all Ubuntu 18.04 machines:

- pthreads
- X11, Xext
- ALSA (pulseaudio on top of this)
- opengl

Now, I know the header files for these libraries must be installed to successfully compile, e.g. `apt install libXXX-dev` however the libraries (.so files) should be already present.
I can successfully link with: `-lX11 -lXext -lpthread -dl -GL`.
However, I cannot find the appropriate linker flags for ALSA (have tried `-lasound` variants to no avail) Any answers I have found online say to install `asound2`, but if I do this, then the distributed binary will require the user to install these libraries also! This shouldn't be necessary!

So, I would really appreciate it if someone could show me the linker flags for the system library ALSA. Thanks!

Comment: Actualy, it's indeed necessary. You can't expect that every Ubuntu user will have any library you think off on their PC. First because it's a waste of space, second it's a security risk, because it creates more opportunities for vulnerabilites. And also it's unnecessary for most people to have headers installed, because only few people will compile anything on their own, when there are pre-build versions of anyhing in repostories, PPAs, snaps, flatpak and so on.

Comment: I state in my question that headers **HAVE** to be installed, but _system libraries_ **SHOULDN'T**. Ubuntu is a gnu/linux OS, meaning it packages together various software into, well, what we know as Ubuntu. If as you say, there is no _system library_ for sound (alsa is one) or hardware accelerated graphics (opengl is one) AFAIK, no **DEFAULT** Ubuntu application could play sound or use accelerated graphics, e.g. rhythmbox, firefox, etc. These applications link to libraries **ALREADY** present on Ubuntu.

Comment: In that case, I didn't understand your question. Pardon me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I was having an issue with the ALSA system library. I was not aware of the versioning symlinking used in some linux libraries. See [stackoverflow q & a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579622/what-is-the-correct-way-to-link-against-shared-libraries). So, although the package `libasound2-dev` seems to install a non-system library in addition to headers, it is in fact a symlink to the most recent linux ASLA system library. Therefore, the binary will run on Ubuntu 18.04, dependency free.
For completeness sake:

```bsh
# libc headers and object files. annoying that gcc is a dependency here.
apt install gcc libc6-dev
# x11 headers
apt install libx11-dev libxext-dev
# opengl headers
apt install libgl1-mesa-dev
# alsa headers and symlink library
apt install libasound2-dev
```